# In Kafka, the "Key" does not match the "Id" when updating the document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

We are trying to take all the records from MongoDB to Kafka using the com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector. The settings are used for connector as follows:

```
{
    "name": "mongo-source",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector",
        "connection.uri": "mongodb:***:27017/?authSource=admin&replicaSet=myMongoCluster&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256",
        "database": "someDb",
        "collection": "someCollection",
        "output.format.value":"json",
        "output.format.key":"json",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable":"false",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable":"false",
        "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "publish.full.document.only": "true",
        "change.stream.full.document":"updateLookup",
        "copy.existing": "true"
    }
}
```

When all documents are initially uploaded from MongoDB to Kafka, the "key" corresponds to the "id" from Mongo document:

```
{"_id": {"_id": {"$oid": "5e54fd0fbb5b5a7d35737232"}, "copyingData": true}}
```

But when a document in MongoDB is updated, an update with a different "key" gets into Kafka:

```
{"_id": {"_data": "82627B2EF6000000022B022C0100296E5A1004A47945EC361D42A083988C14D982069C46645F696400645F0FED2B3A35686E505F5ECA0004"}}
```

Thus, the consumer cannot identify the initially uploaded document and update for it.

Please help me find which settings on the Kafka, Connector or MongoDB side are responsible for this and how I can change the "Key" in Kafka to the same as during the initial upload.

Comment: Vitaly &  @OneCricketeer found any solution here?

Comment: @RaviJain I shared the way I do it in the answer below. Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were facing the same issue and after some search we started using the following config. We defined a avro schema to extract the output schema key. The key is generated consistently and looks like

> Struct{fullDocument._id=e2ce4bfe-d03a-4192-830d-895df5a4b095}

Here **"e2ce4bfe-d03a-4192-830d-895df5a4b095"** is the document id.

```
{
  "change.stream.full.document" : "updateLookup",
  "connection.uri" : "<connection_uri>",
  "connector.class" : "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector",
  "collection": "someCollection",
  "copy.existing" : "true",
  "database" : "someDb",
  "key.converter" : "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
  "key.converter.schemas.enable" : "false",
  "key.serializer" : "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
  "name" : "mongo-source",
  "output.format.key" : "schema",
  "output.json.formatter" : "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.source.json.formatter.SimplifiedJson"
  "publish.full.document.only" : "true",
  "output.schema.key": "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"keySchema\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"fullDocument._id\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}",      
  "tasks.max" : "1",
  "value.converter" : "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
  "value.converter.schemas.enable" : "false"
}
```

Comment: Using the fullDocument._id doesn't work when you enable tombstones on delete because the fullDocument isn't part of the value on a delete. The documentKey._id should be used instead.

In other words, if you have 
"publish.full.document.only.tombstone.on.delete":"true", 

you should use 
"output.schema.key": "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"keySchema\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"documentKey._id\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}",

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to attach `MongoSourceConnector` developed by **mongodb**, not **Debezium**'s. It's because the latter require more complicate permissions than the former. Fortunately, mongodb's connector also support **Log-based CDC**, i.e. insert/update/delete query.

```yaml
connector.class: com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector
```

---

Like Abhra said, you can filter `fullDocument._id` as a key of messages.

Define `publish.full.document.only` and `output.schema.key` config options as follows:

```yaml
output.format.key: schema
output.json.formatter: com.mongodb.kafka.connect.source.json.formatter.SimplifiedJson
publish.full.document.only: true
output.schema.key: "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"keySchema\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"fullDocument._id\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}"
```

If you want **metadata** of the messages or exclude fields, you can use `pipeline` as follows:

```yaml
pipeline: "[{\"$match\": {\"operationType\": \"insert\"}}, {\"$project\": {\"operationType\": 0, \"clusterTime\": 0, \"documentKey\": 0}}]"
```

The last thing you only have to do is transforming Kafka Message using **SMT** (especially, `ExtractField`).

```yaml
transforms: ExtractField
transforms.ExtractField.type: org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key
transforms.ExtractField.field: fullDocument._id
```